# Error while moving to edit page in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I used edit option in user page... its works fine, but when i apply same thing in organization details page... it shows an error. syntax and error are given below....

This is my page name `index.html.erb` which is the in the view name `um_org_data`

```
<% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_data| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= check_box_tag "deleted_ids[]", um_org_data.id %></td>
          <td><%= um_org_data.org_name %></td>
          <td><%= um_org_data.org_description%></td>
          <td><%= um_org_data.offc_addr%></td>
          <td><%= um_org_data.offc_ph%></td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to "<i class='icon-eye-open'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data,"data-original-title" => "View Details", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>
            <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-edit'><i/i>".html_safe, edit_um_org_data_path(um_org_data), "data-original-title" => "Edit", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none'%>


          </td>
      </tr>

        <%end%>
```

The controller name for this View is `um_org_data_controller.rb` and the Model for this view is `um_org_datum.rb`

In database the table name is `um_org_data` and the following are the attributes of the table:

```
id-----> int
org_name-----> varchar(255)
org_description-----> varchar(255)
offc_addr-----> varchar(255)
offc_ph-----> varchar(255)
```

and the Error is following:

```
NoMethodError in Um_org_data#index 

undefined method `edit_um_org_data_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000042ab418>:0x007fa9e46f8f48>

    <td><%= um_org_data.offc_ph%></td>
                   <td>
                     <%= link_to "<i class='icon-eye-open'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data,"data-original-title" => "View Details", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>
                     <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-edit'><i/i>".html_safe, edit_um_org_data_path(um_org_data), "data-original-title" => "Edit", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none'%>


                  </td>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post error now i have edited my question with error details now check that above!

Comment: i have and error in the following line " <%= link_to "<%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-edit'></i>".html_safe, edit_um_org_data_path(um_org_data), "data-original-title" => "Edit", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none'%>"

Comment: what is your controller & model name.

Comment: @rails guy i have mentioned my controller and model name above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route name is incorrect - the edit page is for a single object, so the route should be the singular - ie. `edit_um_org_datum_path(um_org_data)`.

See the output of `rake routes` for more info on what helper methods your routes define for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem exist. you have to define your routes as per your model. not like the instance you are instantiating.

Please do `rake routes | grep um_org_datum` in your terminal. and see the output. you will find your edit routes path there. it will be like:

```
edit_um_org_datum_path(:id)
```

Please change your path to `edit_um_org_datum_path(um_org_data)`

Thanks